# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un DatePicker seleccione la fecha actual automáticamente al iniciar la aplicación?

Tags: java, android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Mi aplicación de Android se basa en un selector de fechas, en el que cada vez que se cambia la fecha se hace una llamada a la base de datos. Sin embargo me gustaría que siempre que se inicie la aplicación se considere que se ha pulsado la fecha actual. ¿Cómo podría hacer eso?¿Hay algún componente que me permita realizarlo?

El código que uso para inicializar el datePicker es el siguiente:

```
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    calendario.init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener({//codigo para conectar a la base de datos});
```

Comment: has probado con esto? CharSequence s  = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format("MMMM d, yyyy ");

Comment: Respuesta editada con mi inserción.

Comment: vale, entonces el problema que tienes no es como recuperar la hora actual, sino como marcarla en tu objeto?

Comment: El problema es que cuando se inicia la aplicación tengo que dar pulsar manualmente la fecha para que cargue la base de datos, y lo que yo quiero es que automáticamente lo haga con la fecha actual. No se si me he explicado.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener` en vez de definir el método y ponerlo como parámetro? Así podrás llamarlo la primera vez con los datos de la fecha actual.

Comment: ahora te entiendo perfectamente, pero la fecha actual la obtienes no? con lo cual solo faltaría indicarle al objeto que se inicie en esa fecha no?

Comment: mira este artículo, inicia el componente DateTimePicker en una fecha concreta: https://programacionymas.com/blog/como-pedir-fecha-android-usando-date-picker/

Comment: ¿Qué es `calendario`? ¿Cómo puedo obtener o dónde almacenas la vista del calendario?

Comment: Calendario es el DatePicker que tengo en la actividad, es una variable DatePicker que la relaciono con lo que tengo en layout

Comment: @G.Corporales , ¿podrías confirmar si mi respuesta solucionó tu problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución sería implementar `DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener` en la clase mediante `implements`:

```
public class TuActividad extends Activity implements DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener
```

Una vez hecho eso implementaría el método de manera habitual:

```
/* Contenido de DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener({código para conectar a la base de datos}); */
@Override
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    /* Aquí tu código */
}
```

Por último puedes indicar dicho método a tu llamada a `calendario.init` y llamarlo inmediatamente después para que lo ejecute con los datos que acabas de cargar en él:

```
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
calendario.init(year, month, day, this);
onDateChanged(calendario, year, month, day);
```

---

Código usado para reproducir el problema:

```
package com.linaresdigital.android.stackoverflow.ejemplo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener {
    DatePicker calendario;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /* Almacenamos la vista para su posterior uso */
        calendario = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        /* Obtenemos fecha actual */
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        /* Iniciamos el calendario con la fecha inicial obtenida */
        calendario.init(year, month, day, this);
        /* Simulamos que hemos actualizado la fecha (envío inicial) */
        onDateChanged(calendario, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        /* Ejemplo que muestra la fecha seleccionada */
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), year + "-" + monthOfYear + "-" + dayOfMonth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, gracias!